# Roots of a 6th degree polynomial over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p>2019$ be a prime number. Consider the polynomial

$$f(x)=(x^2 -3)(x^2 -673)(x^2 -2019)$$

How many roots can $f$ possibly have in the Finite Field $\mathbb F_p?$

I tried with prime $2027$. But it is very tedious checking the roots for the given polynomial. There must be a simple and elegant way of solving this. Please help.

Comment: Note:  $2019=3\times673$

Comment: Do you know the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity?

Comment: in a finite field where $3, 673$, and $2019$ are not $0$, $x^2-3$, $x^2-673$, and $x^2-2019$ each have  $0$ or $2$ roots; furthermore, if any two of them have $2$ roots, then so does the third; e.g.,  if $a^2\equiv3$ and $b^2\equiv2019$, then $(ba^{-1})^2\equiv673$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner's comment shows that it is impossible for this polynomial to have exactly four zeros (4 roots => 6 roots). A fact special to finite fields is that it is impossible for this polynomial not to have any roots at all in $\Bbb{F}_p$. Do you see why?

Comment: @CalvinLin I do not know Quadratic Reciprocity. I will search and find out.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't see why? Is it because of the law mentioned by CalvinLin ?

Comment: It's related to that. Have you covered multiplicativity of the Legendre symbol? If $a$ and $b$ are quadratic non-residues, then $ab$....?

Comment: Alternatively, if you know that there exists a primitive root modulo $p$ for every prime, you can use that instead.

Comment: I understand the point that the polynomial will have either two roots or all six roots in $\mathbb F_p$. The cases nil roots and four roots are ruled out. I have to learn the theory you all have mentioned. Thank you for taking the time to help me understand the problem and the solution to the problem.

Comment: @Jyrki I think it very unlikely for someone who doesn't know about Quadratic Reciprocity to be familiar with Legendre symbols. ;)

Comment: FWIW, there's a gentle introduction to Quadratic Reciprocity in this Number Theory course: http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/~kcrisman/mat338/NTIC.html

Comment: The product of two quadratic residues or non-residues is a residue; the product of a residue and a non-residue is a non-residue

Comment: A minimalist argument: The mapping $S:x\mapsto x^2$ is a homomorphism from the multiplicative group $\Bbb{F}_p^*$ to itself. Its kernel has two elements, so its image contains half the elements (the elements $a$ such that $x^2-a$ has two roots). So $\Bbb{F}_p^*/S(\Bbb{F}_p^*)$ is cyclic of order two. Implying that the product of any two elements not in the image must be in the image.

Comment: Thank you for the crisp explanation. I have started reading about the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity. After that the full meaning of the points made by you will become clear to me.