# Let $p > 2019$ be a prime no. Consider the polynomial $f(x) = (x^2-3)(x^2-673)(x^2-2019)$ How many roots can $f$ possibly have in finite field $F_p$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Let $p > 2019$ be a prime number. Consider the polynomial $f(x) = (x^2-3)(x^2-673)(x^2-2019)$ How many roots can $f$ possibly have in finite field $F_p$ ?

1. $0$
2. $2$
3. $3$
4. $6$

I have seen this question on this site but I could not understand it from there. So I posted this question again. Here I see that $2019 = 3×673$. Also $F_p = \{0,1,2,3,...,p-1\}$, Here $3,673,2019 \in \{0,1,2,3,...,p-1\}$ for $p >2019$. So options 2,3 can be possible. But correct options are $2,4$ and I could not approach.

Comment: is this from a past contest, can you give a link?

Comment: I don't know how to share a link.

Comment: It seems this question was asked before , see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3934622/roots-of-a-6th-degree-polynomial-over-a-finite-field?noredirect=1). No source and no answer is there, but there's enough of an explanation to probably write an answer here.

Comment: I edited the above question. Now options are ready to see.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me see if I can be of help to you.

Comment: Ok, so let's look at the map $f : F_p \to F_p$, given by $f(x) = x^2$. The claim is that $f$ is a multiplicative homomorphism, which can be easily checked. Now, what is the kernel of $f$? (Note : attempts based on my directives can be added to the question). Based on  that, suppose that $673$ is in the image of $f$. How many preimages can $673$ have? Replacing $673$ with $3$ and $2019$, can you prove that $f = 0$ must have an even number of roots?

Comment: One more approach can be using the properties of quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: The point in the other thread was that an even number of $3,673,2019$ are quadratic non-residues modulo $p$. Or,  just one or all three of them are quadratic residues. This leaves $2$ and $6$ as possibilities for the number of solutions.

Comment: So in addition to what @TeresaLisbon explained, it is impossible for there to be either four roots or no roots at all.

Comment: These hints are very nice but I'm a beginner, so please convert hints into solutions in proper form.

Comment: The hints pretty much spell it out. Where did you see this question? Are you sure you have learned the required background concepts? For example, do you know what a quadratic residue is? Is it clear to you that for example $x^2-3\equiv0\pmod p$ has either zero or two solutions ($p>3$)? If not, then you should first learn more elementary material.